# print array of arrays with a separator

Tags: perl, data-dumper

I have written a simple perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

$Data::Dumper::Pair     = '';
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Terse    = 1;

my @A=( [ 1,2 ],[ 3,4,5 ], [ 6,7,8 ]);
print Dumper(@A);
```

The output i get is :

```
> ./temp9.pl
[
          1,
          2
        ]
[
          3,
          4,
          5
        ]
[
          6,
          7,
          8
        ]
```

But what i need is the elements(arrays) to be separated with a comma `,` in between them.
I am much familiar in using Data:Dumper. Is there any fix for this?
The expected output is :

```
[
          1,
          2
        ],
[
          3,
          4,
          5
        ],
[
          6,
          7,
          8
        ]
```

Anothere question i have is is there any way in data dumper where i can add some text before each element in an array?for example here in array of array , can i add "xyz" before the opening brace of each array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED#2**

Try with `print 'my $aRef = ', Dumper(\@A), ";";`. It will print like this:

```
my $aRef = [
  [
    1,
    2
  ],
  [
    3,
    4,
    5
  ],
  [
    6,
    7,
    8P
  ]
]
;
```

If You want to change the output of Dumper you can redirect the stdout to a variable (see [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)).

```
print map { "Something $_\n" } split "\n", Dumper(\@A);
```

Output:

```
Something [
Something   [
Something     1,
Something     2
Something   ],
Something   [
Something     3,
Something     4,
Something     5
Something   ],
Something   [
Something     6,
Something     7,
Something     8
Something   ]
Something ]
```

Comment: Thanks TrueY. Got the idea now.i was missing a `\` before `@A`

Comment: But also is there a way where i can append text to each element here?

Comment: @Vijay: Could you describe what is your goal?

Comment: Why not simply call `my $var = Dumper( \@a );`?

Comment: @dgw: Because I'm stupid! Or just I have a serious code blindness! ;) Corrected! Thx! (_Actually I like the redirection stuff. It is funny anyway_)